# How to export entire xml elements and attributes and save it to SQL Server in one table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, openrowset, xmltable

I wanted to export all elements, attributes of XML sourced from https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/200931393493000150_public.xml. As shown in my code below I was able to create tables using multiple queries. It looks like I have to create multiple tables of multiple elements and attributes which will be tedious process to union all or join accordingly.

My question: is there any way  to create one single table in one go of the entire XML content?

Second question is how do I use `openrowset` to read from XML file stored in SQL Server rather than local directory.

Here is the code I used which working fine to query part of the XML:

```
Create database [IRS-900]
USE [IRS-900]
GO

CREATE TABLE [SampleXML]
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO [SampleXMl](XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 

FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\200931393493000150_public.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;



     DECLARE @targetTable TABLE 
     
     (
        ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
        EIN CHAR(10), 
        AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
        AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
        City VARCHAR(50),
        State CHAR(2),
        ZIPCode CHAR(5)
        
     );

      ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
     
    , rs (xmldata) AS
    (
       SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) AS BulkColumn 
       FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\200931393493000150_public.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
      -- xml file from (https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/200931393493000150_public.xml)  saved to local disk 
    )

    INSERT INTO @targetTable
    --Insert Into FormIndex
    --Insert into IRS900Sample
    SELECT 
       -- c.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'Varchar(100)') AS Keys
         c.value('(EIN/text())[1]', 'CHAR(10)') AS EIN
       , c.value('(USAddress/AddressLine1/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine1
       , c.value('(USAddress/AddressLine2/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine2
       , c.value('(USAddress/City/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS City
       , c.value('(USAddress/State/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS State
       , c.value('(USAddress/ZIPCode/text())[1]','CHAR(5)') AS ZIPCode
    FROM rs AS tbl
       --CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnHeader/Filer')  AS t(c);
         OUTER APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnHeader/Filer')  AS t(c);
       --querying the index 
       --CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes ('/ListBucketResult/Contents') AS t(c);
       --OUTER APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes ('/ListBucketResult/Contents') AS t(c);

    SELECT * FROM @targetTable;
    --select * from FormIndex
    --SELECT * FROM IRS900Sample

 DECLARE @targetTable2 TABLE 
      --create table IRS900Sample
     (
        ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
        NamePerson VARCHAR(50),
        Title VARCHAR(50),
        AverageHoursPerWeek FLOAT,
        IndividualTrusteeOrDirector CHAR(2),
        ReportableCompFromOrganization  CHAR(2),
        ReportableCompFromRelatedOrgs CHAR(2),
        OtherCompensation CHAR(2)
     );

    
      ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
    
    , rs (xmldata) AS
    (
       SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) AS BulkColumn 
      
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\200931393493000150_public.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
      -- xml file from (https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/200931393493000150_public.xml)  saved to local disk 
       
    )

    INSERT INTO @targetTable
    --Insert Into FormIndex
    --Insert into IRS900Sample
    SELECT 
       
         c.value('(NamePerson/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS NamePerson
       , c.value('(Title/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS Title
       , c.value('(AverageHoursPerWeek/text())[1]','float') AS AverageHoursPerWeek
       , c.value('(IndividualTrusteeOrDirector/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS IndividualTrusteeOrDirector
       , c.value('(ReportableCompFromOrganization/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS ReportableCompFromOrganization
       , c.value('(ReportableCompFromRelatedOrgs/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS ReportableCompFromRelatedOrgs
       , c.value('(OtherCompensation/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS OtherCompensation
    FROM rs AS tbl
      
          OUTER APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990/Form990PartVIISectionA')  AS t(c);
        --CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990/Form990PartVIISectionA')  AS t(c);

    SELECT * FROM @targetTable2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is called shredding, i.e. shredding XML, converting it to a rectangular/relational format and eventually loading into table(s).

**Question #1:** Is there any way to create one single table in one go of the entire xml content?

**Answer:** it is possible to load entire XML file as-is into a single column of XML data type.

**Question #2:** How do I use `openrowset` to read from xml file stored in SQL Server rather than local directory?

**Answer:** SQL Server XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` are exactly for that.

Comment: for question number one as you can see  in the code I created an xml table. i.e loaded entire XML file as-is into a single column of XML data type. My question is how to import all elements and attributes to one single table. So i can be able to query as a normal table not as xml data type. The second question is I am using openrowset ( to read from local path ) instead how can I read the file from the one already loaded in the sql server as xml file.  I want to use subquery for openrowset like select * from [IRS-900] ( which is an xml data type i created in sql server )

Comment: @Divola,please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: Sure Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes standardization can help you a lot, even though more steps are needed. In my case, I used the following table valued-function (see below) to convert **ANY XML** file to a SQL Table and from there I can do whatever I want.  The good thing is that I don't need to code for each xml change, it is dynamically converted and I can manage the data as a regular table.

USE:

```
select *  from Utility.FlattenXml('<a>1</a><b></b><c>3</c>')
select field, field  from Utility.FlattenXml('<a>1</a><b></b><c>3</c>') where [yourfield] = [value]
```

PROCEDURE:

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[FlattenXml](@xmlDoc XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH CTE AS ( 

    SELECT 
            1 AS lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
            + N'[' 
            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
            + N']' AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
            x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
            x.query('.') AS this,         
            x.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
    FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/*') a(x)  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
            c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
            CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
            CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
            c.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
            CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)
            
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                                SELECT 
                                                lvl AS Depth,  
                                                Name AS NodeName,  
                                                ParentName, 
                                                ParentPosition, 
                                                NodeType,  
                                                FullPath,  
                                                XPath,  
                                                Position, 
                                                Tree AS TreeView,  
                                                Value,  
                                                this AS XMLData,  
                                                Sort, 
                                                ID
                                                FROM cte  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.Name, 
            p.Position, 
            CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
            p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            1, 
            SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
            + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            NULL,  
            p.Sort,  
            p.ID + 1  
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
    )  

    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
            ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
            NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
    FROM CTE2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , where is the utlity schema coming from ? The other question is  when I put my xml  file stored in  sql table  the function returned empty table. Here is  the function call i used select *  from FlattenXml( 'SELECT [xmldata] FROM [IRS-900].[dbo].[XMLTable] where ID=1 ')  I have thousand xml data files stored in a table I wanted to iterate the XML shredding from. I was just testing the code in one xml data. Thanks again

Comment: I'm sorry the schema is from my DB you can create your own! It really doesn't matter.  The issue is that you are sending the select as a parameter and the function expect and XML. Try this:

DECLARE @x XML

SELECT @x = [xmldata] FROM [IRS-900].[dbo].[XMLTable] where ID=1

select * from [YourSchema].FlattenXml(@x)

Also remember that the function return a table with different formats of the XML, you need to decide which fields you want by changing the select * from [yourschema].flattenxml to the select value, ... from [yourschema].flattenxml